# Using sprintf with mysql_query

Tags: mysql, sql, c, c89

I'm using a mysql snippet that connects to my mysql database (locally) in ANSI C. Everything is working perfectly, but I've been trying to create a function that connects to my database and inserts a new record based on some variables. I'm using sprintf to snag those variables and piece them together to form my SQL query.

## Problem

Once I have my variables and my SQL ready, I send it over to mysql_query. Unfortunately, this does not work as expected, the program crashes and reports a buffer overflow.

Here are pieces of the overall function that may help explain the problem.

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *table = "test_table"; // table is called test_table
char *column = "value"; // column is called value
char *value = "working"; // what value we are inserting
char *query; // what we are sending to mysql_query

sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ('%s')", table, column, value);

if (mysql_query(conn, query)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
  return;
}
```

## Purpose

The purpose of the overall function is so I don't have to keep rewriting SQL insert or update statements in my program. I want to call to one function and pass a few parameters that identify the table, columns and the values of said columns.

Any help would be most appreciated. I'm a bit rusty in C these days.

## Question

Why is mysql_query not able to send the string?

## Changes

This worked based on the comments.

```
const char *query[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];

sprintf((char *)query, "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ('%s')", table, column, value);

if (mysql_query(conn, (const char *)query)) {
```

Comment: Is there a question that I can't see in your "question"? Or did you forget it?

Comment: You never allocate memory for `query`. It doesn't point to any valid location. I suggest you read a good beginners' C programming guide before trying to mess with SQL, because there will be [little Bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com) all over the place.

Comment: And I'm guessing that this code crashes because `query` is a pointer that points to "nowhere".

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. Makes perfect sense. I originally allocated memory, but i got a few warnings. I should have specified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no backing storage for `query`.

It's either set to NULL or some indeterminate value, depending on its storage duration, neither of which will end well :-)

Quick fix is to change it to

```
char query[1000];
```

though any coder worth their salary would also check to ensure buffer overflow didn't occur.

Comment: No problem, I've removed my now-obsolete comment.

Comment: I didn't want to paste the entire function, but yes, it is inside the function.

Comment: I originally set, const char query[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];. This compiles and works with warnings. It also updates the database as your quick fix does. But, mysql_query warns it expect const. Then sprintf warns that it discards const.

Comment: @Fastidious, that's a different issue, one that can probably be fixed with casting.But even being warned about const-ness is better than crashing :-)

Comment: What about "const char *query", "char query_ready[MAX_STRING_LENGTH]" and "query = query_ready;"? This compiled without warning when changing sprintf(query,...) to query_ready. No warning, no crash and worked.

Comment: @Fastidious, that looks okay. You could probably use casting to avoid a second variable but, if it works, go for it. The cost of a second pointer variable is close enough to zero that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Updated the description to reflect my attempt. I'll wait a bit and see if you respond. Then I'll accept this answer because this ideally made it not crash and work as well lead me to the new change listed above.

Comment: Thanks again paxdiablo! I wrote it again, but casted this time and it worked like a charm without the second variable.